# Truncating last two characters from SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, substring, truncate

This will seem rudimentary but trying the substring command to no avail:

Using

```
SUBSTRING('indcode', 1, 4)
```

The values are 6 characters long and I need the last two deleted from them. In short, I need them truncated from 6 to 4.

Output

```
indc
```

Also, in the table `indcode` is column of datatype `char(6)`. Could that be why I get an incorrect syntax error when I use that substring command?

Comment: Remove the ticks from around your column name.

Comment: Also show how you are using it.. I'm assuming just via select but it helps to see.  And provide the specific syntax error.

Comment: I did that and get this:

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
Incorrect syntax near 'indcode'.

All of my indcode values end in 00. So 102100 needs to be 1021.

Comment: You are doing `SELECT SUBSTRING(indcode,1,4) FROM YourTable` correct?

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46006166/edit) your question to include enough code to supply the proper context to your question, i.e. the _whole_ SQL statement you are using.

Comment: Will SELECT SUBSTRING(indcode,1,4) FROM YourTable display it or actually delete it?

Comment: No. Why would a select query delete anything?

Comment: It will display it.. if you want to actually update it, you would just do `UPDATE YourTable SET indcode = SUBSTRING(indcode,1,4)`.. but you should certainly validate the change with a select first.

Comment: Also: `char(6)` will **always** be 6 characters long - if you try to store a shorter string, it'll be padded to the defined length (of 6 characters here) with spaces.

Comment: @AaronDietz. Thanks, I had never touched sql before last week so pardon my naivete.

Comment: @TimWilcox NP, just in future questions if you don't know the query that's fine, but show whatever you have, and most importantly, show your current data and your expected output.  Most users here could answer this immediately if the data in the comments was included in the original question, and you wouldn't get downvotes... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `LEFT ( character_expression , integer_expression )`  as

`LEFT(indcode, 4)` if `indcode` is a column name.
This would trim your field to size 4 from left.